# How to apply ng-if in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am retrieving data from service in the form.

```
[["Sql Injection",0],["Proxy Abuse",0],["Spam",0],["Information and Source Code Leakage",0],["System Command Injection",0],["Cross-Site Request Forgery",0],["Session Hijacking",0],["PHP Injection",0],["Request Anomaly",0],["Local/Remote File Inclusion",0],["Cross-Site Scripting",0]].
```

Now i want that if counts of each attack type are zero then nothing display. How can i handle this through ng-if.
Template code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 b-r b-light no-border-xs" ng-show="webSummary[0]">
    <highchart id="chart1" config="webConfig" class="span9" ></highchart>           
</div>
```

Comment: ng-if="webSummary.length"

Comment: It doesn't help, i tried it already.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.webSummary = [["Sql Injection",0],["Proxy Abuse",0],["Spam",0],["Information and Source Code Leakage",0],["System Command Injection",0],["Cross-Site Request Forgery",0],["Session Hijacking",0],["PHP Injection",0],["Request Anomaly",0],["Local/Remote File Inclusion",0],["Cross-Site Scripting",0]];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="col-md-6 b-r b-light no-border-xs"  
       ng-repeat="ws in webSummary"
       ng-if="ws[1]">
    <highchart id="chart1" config="webConfig" class="span9"></highchart>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: good answer but need not to display visualization when all attacks counts are zero.

Comment: I have added a comment in the code: `// For demo: ["System Command Injection",2]`

Comment: @AbdulMajeed I have updated the answer based on your original array `webSummary`... Now do not show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<div class="col-md-6 b-r b-light no-border-xs" ng-if="checkAttackCount()">
    <highchart id="chart1" config="webConfig" class="span9" ></highchart>           
</div>
```

In controller

```
function checkAttackCount(){    
  for(var i=0;i<webSummary.length;i++){
    if(webSummary[i][1]>0){
      return true;
    }
  }       
  return false;
}
```